# Android studio spacing

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

How to enlarge the spaces in Android Studio between the code prats?

[image]

For example between "private" "and void" in the screenshot above and the tab spaces
(Like in eclipse)

Comment: It looks like you have modified the font. Are you sure you use monospace font for everything? Even the brackets are too narrow...

Comment: Yes, I didn't touch the font, only changed the font size

Comment: So check if the font is monospace and not "system font" or similar...

Comment: The most interesting part is when I setted the font to Consolas, everything looks fine like in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You can put spaces in specific places where you want based on coding style.